# Vector subscript out of range MVS2013

Tags: c++, vector

Here is some of my code I'm using to find the MST of a graph.I use scanf to input an edge in a struct and store them in a vector which has the edge objects. I don't understand why I'm getting the "vector subscript out of range error"  since I initialized me vector size.

```
struct GraphEdge
{
    int x, y, weight;
    void readinput()
    {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &y, &weight);

    }
    bool operator<(const GraphEdge &e) const
    {
        return weight < e.weight;
    }
};

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        int n, m;
        int total_weight = 0;
        scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
        if (!n && !m)
            break;
        int res = 0;
        vector<GraphEdge> edge(m);
        for (int i = 0; i < edge.size(); i++)
        {
            edge[i].readinput();
            cout << edge[i].x << " " << edge[i].y << endl;
            res += edge[i].weight;
            //cout << i << endl;
        }
        sort(edge.begin(), edge.end());
        union_find uf;
        uf.init(n);
        int cnt = 0, mst = 0;
        for (int i = 0; cnt < n - 1 && i < m; i++)
        {
            if (uf.dstunion(edge[i].x, edge[i].y))
            {
                res -= edge[i].weight;
                cnt++;
                mst += edge[i].weight;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", res);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated. Recommend checking the return from `scanf` as well as `if (!n && !m)`. If `scanf` fails, `n` and `m` are undefined and the bad may happen.

Comment: Will do. Thanks

Comment: When I comment all of the `union_find` stuff (because it's not provided) I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Recommend adding `union_find`. Unrelated, why not roll `union_find::init` into the `union_find` constructor? seems a better place for it because it make it impossible to have an uninitialized `union_find` floating around.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program one line at a time, examine the values of all variables, and observe the program's logical execution flow, what observations did you make? This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. No exceptions. At the very least your debugger will tell you how large the array is, and what was the attempted out of range index, and why.

Comment: of course I've defined the union_find class but I didn't think it was really relevant to my issue since my problem is several lines before I use union_find

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some more work to reduce this to a [mcve].